# npm install -g grunt-cli failed in Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, gruntjs

I try to run next command in **Linux**:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

The message I get is next:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: grunt-cli
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /usr/local/grunt/npm-debug.log npm
```

Thanks everyone for help

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Comment: Yes. I can't to install grunt in Linux. In Windows everything works well.

Comment: No, it isn't. You do not have a problem with code you write, but with the installation of software. This is a question for http://www.superuser.com. Please see the [introductionary tour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) for what appropriate questions are.

Comment: I have a problem with GruntJS when I try to use it in Linux. superuser.com. it's not the place for questions about Grunt. I hope someone who has this problem can help me to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you want to use sudo for global installs... Jesus, that's what I call advice resistant...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recommend to use sudo for your npm installations (any sudo npm install), it seems like you need to update your repository, I'm not sure whet distro you are using but if debian or ubuntu you should do something like:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

for more info read [how to install node from npm](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager)

Comment: First, uninstall the outdated version (optional, but I think this fixed an issue I was having with global modules not being pathed in). sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm    And after, what you said. Thanks