# ubuntu npm install failed to fetch

Tags: node.js

I'm getting an error when I attempt to `npm install` a particular package.

These commands worked fine:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

At this point, `npm` is installed, since `npm -v` works properly.

But when I attempted to *use* `npm` to install a package I got an error:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

> ```
> npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: grunt-cli
> npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
> npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
> npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
> npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
> npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
> npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
> npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
> npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
> npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
> npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
> npm ERR! You may report this log at:
> npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
> npm ERR! or use
> npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/jado/sourceFromGit/JADO-FROM-GIT/npm-debug.log npm
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-35-generic
> npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
> npm ERR! cwd /home/jado/sourceFromGit/JADO-FROM-GIT
> npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
> npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: grunt-cli
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/jado/sourceFromGit/JADO-FROM-GIT/npm-debug.log
> npm not ok
> ```

Comment: That's a very old version of node and a sort of old version of npm!

Comment: I edited the body to give a (vague) description of the error at the top of the block.  Then I highlighted both your code and the response in the standard StackOverflow way.  I also cleaned up the grammar a bit.  Good luck!

Comment: Have you looked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630831/npm-install-g-grunt-cli-failed-in-linux ?